# Decomposing a denominator in terms of principal value

Tags: limits, contour-integration, dirac-delta, cauchy-principal-value

I am trying to understand a step made in a physics textbook ( Lectures on Quantum Field Theory, by Ashok Das ). But I don't even know what the formula is called, or what are the keywords. So I couldn't even google it.

On page 253, in equation (6.128 ), the author decomposes a denominator "in the standard manner" :

$$ \underset{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+}{ lim} \frac{1}{k'_0 - k_0 - i \epsilon} = \frac{1}{k'_0 - k_0 } + i \pi \delta(k'_0 - k_0) \tag{6.128}$$

and he says that the first term on the RHS represents the principal value. Note that this denominator appears under an integral on $dk'_0$. Can anyone explain how this formula comes about? Any references are welcome.

To me, it seems that it somehow comes from complex contour integration.

( I have tried to keep it succinct and relevant to math, but I can produce more context if needed. )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not very difficult. We have
$$
\frac{1}{t-i\epsilon}
= \frac{t+i\epsilon}{t^2+\epsilon^2}
= \frac{t}{t^2+\epsilon^2}+i\frac{\epsilon}{t^2+\epsilon^2}
.
$$
Here the first term clearly tends to $\frac{1}{t}$ as $\epsilon\to 0.$ That it is the principal value might not be as clear, but perhaps you can accept it. For the second term we integrate it against a well-behaved function $\phi$ and make a substitution $t=\epsilon s$:
$$
\int \frac{\epsilon}{t^2+\epsilon^2} \phi(t) \, dt
= \int \frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon^2 s^2+\epsilon^2} \phi(\epsilon s) \, \epsilon\,ds
= \int \frac{1}{s^2+1} \phi(\epsilon s) \, ds
\\
\to \int \frac{1}{s^2+1} \phi(0) \, ds
= \pi \phi(0)
= \int \pi\delta(s) \, \phi(s) \, ds
.
$$

Comment: This argument has always made me uneasy: e.g., if the first of the two summands "goes to" $1/t$ (as a distribution? pointwise?...), why didn't the $1/(t-i\epsilon)$ already do that? And so on...

Answer (score 2):

This is sometimes known as the Sokhotski-Plemelj formula.

Other keywords: Hilbert transform.

Among the zillions of discussions of this visible on the internet, I do have a note about it, at
[https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/~garrett/m/v/hilbert_transform.pdf](https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/%7Egarrett/m/v/hilbert_transform.pdf)